# Select a radio button to parse a webpage in powershell

Tags: powershell-3.0

I need to select the expandble view first, then run the Invoke-WebRequest.

```
<span style="margin-right:6px;font-size:11pt;">
    <input id="radCollapse" type="radio" name="results" value="radCollapse" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;radCollapse\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" />
    <label for="radCollapse"> Collapse-able view</label>
</span>
<span style="font-size:11pt;">
    <input id="radExpanded" type="radio" name="results" value="radExpanded" checked="checked" />
    <label for="radExpanded">Search-able Expanded view</label>
</span>
```

Webpage is here: http://jailroster.mctx.org/

Comment: <span style="margin-right:6px;font-size:11pt;"><input id="radCollapse" type="radio" name="results" value="radCollapse" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;radCollapse\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" /><label for="radCollapse"> Collapse-able view</label></span>
  <span style="font-size:11pt;"><input id="radExpanded" type="radio" name="results" value="radExpanded" checked="checked" /><label for="radExpanded"> Search-able Expanded view</label></span>
  </div>

Answer (score 0):

You can have a click event here by using IE comObject.

Eg:-

```
$IE = New-Object -ComObject "Internetexplorer.Application"
$IE.Navigate('URL')
$IE.Visible = $true
$Doc = $IE.Document
$radExpanded = $Doc.GetElementByID('radExpanded')
$radExpanded.Click()
```

This will do a click event to the Web page.

regards,

kvprasoon